# Unpacking list with tuple in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

let's say, we have this list with tuple

```
general = [(a, b, c)]
```

and I want to unpack it.

Why doesn't this work:

```
[value, value1, value2] = general
```

But this does?

```
[temp] = general
value, value1, value2 = temp
```

Shouldn't it be the same?

Are there other alternative, shorter ways to do this?

Comment: *"Shouldn't it be the same?"* — No. The second one is unpacking *twice*, which makes sense, since you have two levels of nesting.

Comment: You can do "value, value1, value2 = general[0]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

general is a list, so what you're trying to do here `[value, value1, value2] = general` is assignate your value to the ones in the list, but here your list has only one element which is your tuple

that's why when you do `[temp] = general` you assignate temp to the unique value of general.

so what you could do is `[value, value1, value2] = general[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Unpacking is roughly the inverse of packing. When packing data like this:

```
general = [(a, b, c)]
```

It can be unpacked by swapping the assignment like this:

```
[(a, b, c)] = general
```

Using a flatter or deeper pattern, such as `[a, b, c] = general` or `[[(a, b, c)]] = general`, does not match the data and thus fails to unpack. An intermediate assignment, such as `[temp] = general`, can be used to reduce/increase the depth but is not needed when the proper pattern is used directly.

Answer (score 0):

since `general` is a list containing the tuple, you should *unpack* the list containing the tuple first, and then unpacking the tuple to get the values

```py
general = [(a, b, c)]
value1, value2, value3 = general[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is working correctly. You are trying to save objects within a tuple within an array to multiple objects. Please try to unpack it once first.

This will work fine:

```
value, value1, value2 = [(a, b, c)][0]
```

Comment: Or double unpacking: `([value, value1, value2],) = general`